# Up to date Moral Philosophy textbooks for self-study

Tags: ethics, reference-request

I wonder if there's an up to date account in moral philosophy that can be used in principle as a textbook for university courses. I have digged a little bit but I have only found for example [Paley's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0865973814) book, which seems even in language a little bit old.

Comment: [Cahn's Exploring Ethics](https://archive.org/details/exploringethicsi0000cahn) is a fairly good recent anthology. [Kenny's Philosophy in the Modern World, v.4](https://ndpr.nd.edu/news/philosophy-in-the-modern-world-a-new-history-of-western-philosophy-volume-4/) has chapters on ethics.

Comment: Thank you, these are precisely the type of sources I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following books, which I'd add to the books cited above, are useful, up to date guides to ethics.

Bernard Williams, Morality: An Introduction to Ethics, Published by CAMBRIDGE UNIVERSITY PRESS, United Kingdom (2012). ISBN 10: 1107604761 ISBN 13: 9781107604766 is well worth reading. It is brief, focused and the work of one of the most distinguished moral philosophers of the second half of the 20th century.

Simon Blackburn, Being Good: A Short Introduction to Ethics, ISBN 10: 0192853775 / ISBN 13: 9780192853776
Published by Oxford Paperbacks, 2002.

Torbjorn Tannsjo, Understanding Ethics: An Introduction to Moral Theory, SBN 10: 0748616381 / ISBN 13: 9780748616381
Published by Edinburgh University Press, 2002.

Frank Scalambriuno, Introduction to Ethics: A Primer for the Western Tradition. ISBN 10: 1524916943 / ISBN 13: 9781524916947
Published by Kendall Hunt Publishing, 2016.

To be taken last as assuming prior knowledge:

Mark Schroeder, Explaining the Reasons We Share: Explanation and Expression in Ethics, ISBN 10: 0198713800 / ISBN 13: 9780198713807
Published by Oxford University Press, United Kingdom, 2014.